# Taking a photo with PhoneGap programmatically

Tags: cordova, camera

I am looking for a way to take a photo using phonegap programmatically.  For example the app can initiate on its own the camera, snap photo and then return to the application with the photo for upload to a server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is late, but Cordova now has its own plugin. Check out the docs [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera). Depending on what version of PhoneGap you're using, it might have the plugin already, or it may not.

In your terminal, just do

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

And in your javascript code and whatnot, you can do something like this:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
});

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

This will prompt your device to take a picture, then if it succeeds it will return you the image data URL to parse and insert into the image element.

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to write a plugin in order to do this.

Comment: Agreed. For this you need to write your own code/plugin. If you want to do this on an Event, would be easier.